# how to show popups when I switch between tabs using mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup

I created a class named Popup

```
  public partial class Popup : Window 
    {
        private DispatcherTimer dT = new DispatcherTimer();
        public Popup ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dT.Tick += new EventHandler(dT_Tick);
            dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            dT.Start();
        }
        private void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dT.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

And I created a property named SelectedIndexOfTabControl to bind to SelectedIndex property of the tabControl in MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
    public int SelectedIndexOfTabControl
      {
       get
       {
          return selectedIndexOfTabControl;
       }
       set
       {
          if (selectedIndexOfTabControl != value)
             {
                 selectedIndexOfTabControl = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged();
                 CreatePopup();
              }
        }
      }

    private void CreatePopup()
      {
           var popup = new Popup ();
           popup.Show();
      }
```

Finally I bound SelectedIndex property to SelectTabControlIndex in MainWindow.xaml

```
   <TabControl Grid.Row="0"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndexOfTabControl, Mode=TwoWay}">

     <TabItem TabIndex="0">
            <TabItem.Header>
               Tab Zero
            </TabItem.Header>

                ...

   </TabItem>

   <TabItem TabIndex="1">
            <TabItem.Header>
              Tab One
            </TabItem.Header>

                ...

  </TabItem>

  <TabItem TabIndex="2">
            <TabItem.Header>
              Tab Two
            </TabItem.Header>

                ...

  </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

Popups are displayed correctly on first switching. But in the next changing, the tab I selected first remains selected. For example I switch to Tab One, then I switch to Tab Two, Tab One is still displayed.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need Mode=TwoWay in the index property. "SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndexOfTabControl, Mode=TwoWay}". Just remove the mode and if still doesn't work, set "NotifyOnTargetChanged = true and updatepropertytrigger"

Comment: You don't show popups and dialogs from the view model (as well as you don't create them there, of course). These are UI elements and must therefore be handled in the view alone. Usually you would add the Popup to your layout in XAML and then bind Popup.IsOpen to a ToggleButton.IsChecked or to a boolean property in general. This property can be in your view model too.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the existing ToolTip class to achieve your goal.